# How to execute a query with two metrics in Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus

I am using Prometheus to query metrics from Apache Flink. I want to measure the number of records In and Out per second of a Map function. When I query two different metrics in Prometheus, the chart only shows one of them.

```
flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsInPerSecond{operator_name="Map"} 
or flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsOutPerSecond{operator_name="Map"}
```

[image]
Does not matter if I change the operator `or` to `and`. The chart shows only the first (`flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsInPerSecond`). I also have tried to edit the Prometheus config file `/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml` but I don't have too much experience on Prometheus and there is something wrong in my configuration. I was basing my solution on [this post](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-labels-from-legacy-metric-names).

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
  - job_name: 'node_exporter'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9100']   
  - job_name: 'flink'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9250', 'localhost:9251', '192.168.56.20:9250']
    metrics_path: /
# HOW TO ADD THE OPERATOR NAME ON THE METRIC NAME?
    metric_relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: '(flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator)_(\w+)'
      replacement: '${2}'
      target_label: pool
      - source_labels: [__name__]
      regex: '(flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator)_(\w+)'
      replacement: '${1}_bytes'
      target_label: __name__
```

Comment: The thing is that Prometheus allows using `or` (union), `and` (intersection), and `unless` (complement) as an operation on sets (https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators). I don't know how to show two distinct metrics on the same chart in order to compare them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to select multiple metric names with a single PromQL query by using a regular expression filter on `__name__` label:

```
{__name__=~"flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecords(In|Out)PerSecond",operator_name="Map"}
```

See docs about the `__name__` label [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#instant-vector-selectors).

There is another solution when using Prometheus-compatible query engine such as [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) by using [union](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#union) function:

```
union(
 
 flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsInPerSecond{operator_name="Map"},
 
 flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsOutPerSecond{operator_name="Map"}
)
```

Note that selecting multiple time series via `__name__` regexp can result in `vector cannot contain metrics with the same labelset` error if the selected series are wrapped in any PromQL function. For example:

```
max_over_time(
 
 {__name__=~"flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecords(In|Out)PerSecond",operator_name="Map"}[5m]
)
```

This is because Prometheus removes metric names from input series when applying PromQL functions. [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) from VictoriaMetrics provides a solution for this issue - `keep_metric_names` modifier (see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#keep_metric_names) for details):

```
max_over_time(
 
 {__name__=~"flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecords(In|Out)PerSecond",operator_name="Map"}[5m]
)
keep_metric_names
```

P.S. I work on VictoriaMetrics and MetricsQL.

Comment: When designing a new schema, is there a performance or storage (dis)advantage in separating series in different metrics like that, vs. having _one_ series `..._numRecordsPerSecond` with a label `operation=In|Out`? Why [move the label values into the metric name](https://www.robustperception.io/cardinality-is-key) if the label can only have two values?

Comment: It is recommended to allocate a separate metric name per each logical thing (for example, network bandwidth, memory usage, requests count, temperature, etc.). This will simplify further querying, grouping and filtering for this data. See https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/ for more details.

Comment: What about very closely related things, for example the price and volume of one stock trade that occurred at a specific time? InfluxDB allows multiple values per point, but Prometheus only one. In the client I want something like `AAPL{price=100, volume=5} time` conceptually. I could create 2 metrics `stock_price` and `stock_volume`, or 1 metric with a label having values `price` and `volume`, but either way, when querying, these two series would need to be joined on the client using the timestamp as a key, which seems wasteful and much more complex than InfluxDB. Is there a better way?

Comment: It is OK to have `stock_price` and `stock_volume` metrics. PromQL allows performing arithmetic calculations on metrics with different names. For example, `stock_volume / stock_price` would return the number of shares.

Comment: See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) for details on PromQL capabilities

Answer (score 12):

First of all, for more complex graphing you should definitely investigate [Grafana](https://grafana.com/).
The built-in Prometheus graphs are useful eg. for debugging, but definitely more limited. In particular one graph will only display the results of one query.

Now for a hack that I definitely do not recommend:

```
flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsInPerSecond{operator_name="Map"}
or
label_replace(flink_taskmanager_job_task_operator_numRecordsOutPerSecond{operator_name="Map"}, "distinct", "foo", "job", ".*")
```

Since, [as documented](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators)

> `vector1 or vector2` results in a vector that contains all original elements (label sets + values) of `vector1` and additionally all elements of `vector2` which do not have matching label sets in `vector1`.

you can add a new label that is not present in the labels on the first vector to the second vector and thus keep all elements from both.

Comment: thanks @Michal. I am also using Grafana. However, why do you mean more complex graphing? Is it easier to do in Grafana? How should I solve it using Grafana?

Comment: @Felipe I mean in Grafana you could simply add several queries to one panel.

Comment: @Felipe: can you please change the accepted answer to [the one provided by the VictoriaMetrics lead dev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71651792/1269037)?

Comment: Both answers solve my problem. The second was a bit late. But indeed it shows 2 ways to do the same. I personally prefer to use only prometheus and not install another library "VictoriaMetrics". However I have saw a few answers that it simplies some complex prometheus queries. I will consider that VictoriaMetrics might pays off to have another library on top of prometheus. Thank you for letting me know :+1: