# Need two Prometheus metric values in a single promql query

Tags: join, prometheus, grafana, promql

I need two Prometheus metric values in a single query. My metric1 is `http_request_duration_seconds_bucket` and metric2 is `http_request_duration_seconds_count`
I would like to have my query output in below table format.
`Label1, Label2, metric1, metric2`. Where `label1` and `label2` are common for both metrics.
Can anyone help with the promql query?

Answer (score 0):

You [can't do that with Prometheus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490701/how-to-execute-a-query-with-two-metrics-in-prometheus/71651792#comment126871579_71651792), because its [data model only supports one value per sample](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/data_model/).

To store multiple values per sample, you need to use a time-series database that supports [fields](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/concepts/key_concepts/), such as InfluxDB.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `or` binary operator in [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#binary-operator-precedence).

```
http_request_duration_seconds_bucket or 
http_request_duration_seconds_count
```

Here is a [demo working](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=alertmanager_alerts_received_total%20or%20alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h) example using `instance` as a common label for two different metrics

```
alertmanager_alerts_received_total or
alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total
```

Result:

```
alertmanager_alerts_received_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", status="firing", version="v1"}
0
alertmanager_alerts_received_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", status="firing", version="v2"}
635876
alertmanager_alerts_received_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", status="resolved", version="v1"}
0
alertmanager_alerts_received_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", status="resolved", version="v2"}
0
alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", version="v1"}
0
alertmanager_alerts_invalid_total{instance="demo.robustperception.io:9093", job="alertmanager", version="v2"}
```

Comment: As the OP said in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69268408/1269037) (which should be a comment), this doesn't solve their use case. [Prometheus doesn't support multiple fields per sample.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69240896/need-two-prometheus-metric-values-in-a-single-promql-query/71794409#71794409)

Comment: @DanDascalescu , I would not take it so religiously. In order words, I would say that "It is possible to do it, but you may consider using another timeseries database to achieve a proper solution with respect to the data model".